# Retain count after creating NSString

Tags: iphone

I am creating a object which is type of NSString by the below method

```
NSString *str = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:@"aaaaaaaaaaaaaaa"];
    NSLog(@"retain count == %d",[str retainCount]);
```

after that i just printing the retain count value which is

2010-10-29 17:04:03.939 Example [1580:207] retain count == 2147483647

can any one answer this why here log is printing such garbage value

Thanks,

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You're creating an immutable NSString object from a string literal. String literals are created at compile time and live for the whole run-time of your program - so it cannot be deallocated and retain/release has no effect on it. For optimization (as your NSString is immutable anyway) `-initWithString:` method can just return the string passed to it and so that string literal address becomes assigned to your str variable.

If you change your initialization code to `-initWithFormat:` then I suppose you'll get expected retain count value

Comment: `initWithString:` cannot assign anything to its caller's variables. It can, however, be implemented to simply return the string it was passed when copying the string would provide no benefit.

Comment: @Peter, you're absolutely right. I corrected the answer (hope my English is not letting me down again here :( )

Answer (score 18):

## Do not use -retainCount.

The absolute retain count of an object is meaningless.

You should call `release` exactly same number of times that you caused the object to be retained.  No less (unless you like leaks) and, certainly, no more (unless you like crashes).

See the [Memory Management Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmRules.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000994-BAJHFBGH) for full details.

---

In this specific case, you caused one `retain` with the call to `alloc` and, thus, you need to call `release` (or `autorelease`) once somewhere, anywhere, in your code.

Comment: Just to clarify for people new to this, `autorelease` also counts as a call to `release`.

Answer (score 1):

constants and literals have retain count = INT_MAX, they can't be released as they are allocated separately not on heap with other objects (afaik)

Answer (score 0):

Your value is UINT_MAX=0x7FFFFFFF

You might override this method in a class to implement your own reference-counting scheme. For objects that never get released (that is, their release method does nothing), this method should return UINT_MAX, as defined in limits.h.

It is static string, then object can not be dealloc.